# OCI connection string... need help

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Does anyone know the OCI connection string used for the dbname parameter in the function OCILogon() for the oracle 10g C API ?

I know you can specify the tnsnames.ora entry for the service, but does it have the ability to take something like: oci:connect:myserver.com:1521/myservicename ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to specify dbname as follows (without tnsnames.ora):

> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)))

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following format for dbname:

`[//]host[:port][/service name]`

You can read more on subject here:
[Database Connection Strings for OCI Instant Client](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci01int.htm#LNOCI16167)